# Ssh(sftp) with certificate via Nautilus in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, nautilus, sshfs

Before I connected to my server via Nautilus (sftp).
Now I moved to Amazon EC2, and there's just one way connect to server (ubuntu 10.10 too), using `ssh -i mycert.pem`, no password, just certificate.
How can I connect to the server using Nautilus, just like i did before?
In other way I guess I can disable certificate by making some changes in /etc/ssh/ssh_config,but not sure what to do.

UPD:
Finally i found solution by using sshfs, more explanation here [How to mount Amazon ec2 drive locally - fuse + sshfs?](http://www.emreakkas.com/linux-tips/how-to-mount-amazon-ec2-drive-locally-fuse-sshfs)

and googling by keywords sshfs + amazon ec2

UPD2:

```
ssh-add /path/to/my_cert.pem
```

and after this connection to sftp via nautilus also working fine

Comment: yeah sshfs is nice too; you'll still have solved exactly the same problems - but the main thing is it works for you :)

Comment: it works, but seems little slower then gvfs. in any case, as more solutions, it's better)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't quite know what you mean by *"I guess I can disable certificate"* when you just said *"and there's just one way connect [...] just certificate"*?

I guess you'd like to have something more like this in .ssh/config. Append a section like the following 5 lines to any existing ~/.ssh/config (i.e. /home/sehe/.ssh/config)

```
Host myec2host
HostName 151.47.12.88
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mycert.pem
Compression yes
```

Note

1. Replace `myec2host` by the *alias* that you want to access the ec2 instance by
2. Replace the IP address by the external (optionally elastic) IP address of your instance
3. Replace `~/.ssh/mycert.pem` by the full path to your private key (usually the keypair) you registered the instance with; *I copied the name `mycert.pem` from your own question, so it is probably that file*
4. Any other options (like Compression) are optional. By default, [Ubuntu images on ec2 (especially the ones from Canonical) should be logged onto using user `ubuntu`; `root` won't work](http://alestic.com/2009/04/ubuntu-ec2-sudo-ssh-rsync)

Of course [`man ssh_config`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/ssh_config/) will do miracles for the details. Also, http://alestic.com/ is an excellent resource on Ubuntu+EC2 (just make sure you don't confuse the Alestic and Canonical images). Lastly there is [the google group for ec2ubuntu](http://groups.google.com/group/ec2ubuntu) which has been very helpful to starters.

---

This way you can just point Nautilus at the server 'my3c2host' and get the reset for free. If the key is protected with a passphrase, you can use a passphrase agent (seahorse, gpg-agent... dunno by heart)

Comment: I didn't understand how to do it. can you give me link with some explanation?